# vs code run python file as a part of a shell script

Tags: python, shell, visual-studio-code

I have a shell script, which sets up the requirement environment variables for my python script.
Current Working Scenario:
Terminal$ configured_python sample_python_file.py

Desired / Ideal Scenario:
vs code --> Editing python file --> Run Python file as a part of shell script

Unfortunately I can't use a conda environment, in order to preset the python environment variables, as of now (owing to my shortcomings on the knowledge of using preconfigured python interpreter). Anyways that's an another question.

Any help would be really appreciated regarding the correct settings in the vs code directly.

Thanks,
Ajay.

Comment: there is an extension named 'code-runner'. check it out, maybe this is what you need.

Comment: Thank you. The custom command is solved my problem.

Comment: By any chance, do you think it is possible to run a python script once a application has been started, in order to load the required files and run the simulations automatically. Sparing me the clicks of loading up the files.